# Use RegEx to find 100$ in text c#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to search **100$** through the RegEx. But unable to find its pattern is as above.

> \b100\$\b

However, if the text contains **100$1** then it displays properly.
But I want to do exact search.

Comment: What do you tried? What are examples which are you using?

Comment: `\b100\$\b` well exactly i am trying to do is findind the exact term match even it has special characters

Answer (score 0):

Word boundaries only work with word characters, not `$`.  Try using this regex:

```
\b100\$(?=\s|\$)
```

This will match `100$`, where what follows the `$` is either whitespace or the end of the line.

### Demo